# Unit test for Android (kotlin) does not pass all at once, but only separately

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I have written unit tests that individually succeed, but as soon as I run them as a whole class I get a failure.
Help me figure it out.

my tests:

```
 class IntercomViewModelTests: TestViewModel() {

private val apiRepository = mockk<ApiRepository>()
private val storageWrapper = mockk<StorageWrapper>()

@Before
fun before() {
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    clearMocks(apiRepository)
    clearMocks(storageWrapper)
}

@Test
fun `loadData and return success`() {
    val linphoneDataRequestBodyData = LinphoneDataRequestBodyData(
        0,
        "test",
        "test",
        "test",
        arrayListOf(IntercomCardsRequestBodyData(0, "test", "test", "test", 0)),
        arrayListOf(IntercomEventsRequestBodyData(0, "test", "test", "test")),
        "test",
        "test",
        "test"
        )
    val linphoneAccountsRequestBodyData = LinphoneAccountsRequestBodyData(
        0,
        "test",
        "test",
        "test",
        "test"
    )
    val viewModel = IntercomViewModel(apiRepository, storageWrapper)
    coEvery { apiRepository.getIntercomDataByToken(any()) } returns LinphoneDataResponseData(
        arrayListOf(linphoneDataRequestBodyData),
        arrayListOf(linphoneAccountsRequestBodyData)
    )

    runTest { viewModel.loadData("test") }
    val result = viewModel.needToInitNavigation.value

    Assert.assertEquals(true, result)
}

@Test
fun `loadData and return exception`() {
    val viewModel = IntercomViewModel(apiRepository, storageWrapper)
    coEvery { apiRepository.getIntercomDataByToken(any()) } returns null

    runTest { viewModel.loadData("test") }
    val result = viewModel.needToShowError.value

    Assert.assertEquals(true, result)
}
```

}

TestViewModel():

```
 open class TestViewModel {

    @get:Rule
    val testViewModelScopeRule = TestViewModelScopeRule()

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    val mockkRule = MockKRule(this)

    @RelaxedMockK
    lateinit var baseViewModel: BaseViewModel
}
```

If I understood correctly, it's about the coroutines. But I have configured switching dispatchers

TestViewModelScopeRule():

```
class TestViewModelScopeRule(
    private val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
) : TestWatcher() {

override fun starting(description: Description?) {
    super.starting(description)
    Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
}

override fun finished(description: Description?) {
    super.finished(description)
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
}
```

}

viewModel:

```
class IntercomViewModel(val apiRepository: ApiRepository, val storageWrapper: StorageWrapper) :
ViewModel() {

var needToInitNavigation = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
var needToShowError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
private val intercomList = ArrayList<IntercomData>()

fun loadData(intercomToken: String) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val intercomDataResponse: LinphoneDataResponseData?
        try {
            intercomDataResponse = apiRepository.getIntercomDataByToken(intercomToken)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e, "[loadData] error")
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { needToShowError.value = true }
            return@launch
        }
        if (intercomDataResponse == null) {
            Timber.w("[loadData] intercomDataResponse == null")
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { needToShowError.value = true }
            return@launch
        }
        castModel(intercomDataResponse)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            needToInitNavigation.value = true
        }
    }
}}
```

I also tried adding dispatchers switching to the before and after methods - it didn't help(

Comment: Try moving `result` and assertion into `runTest { }` blocks.